# I wanna make a function of 1 variable which is a string.(number1 mathematical operation(+ - * / ) number2) .e.g. calculate_from_string(5+3) returns 8

Tags: python, casting, python-3.7

def calculate_from_string('string'):

#I tried doing a lot of things that didnt work out for me and I cant use the eval function in this code.

Comment: You can check which operator is used and then split by it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating a mathematical expression in a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2371436/evaluating-a-mathematical-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 2):

```
OPERATIONS = {
    "+":lambda x,y:x+y,
    "*":lambda x,y:x*y,
    "-":lambda x,y:x-y,
    "/":lambda x,y:x/y
}

def calculate(string):
    global OPERATIONS
    import re # regular expresion module
    # "8 + 8" is the same as "8+8"
    # but "-8 * 8" is not "- 8 * 8" so be careful
    pattern = re.findall(r"(-?\d)[ \t]*(.)[ \t]*(-?\d)",string)
    # pattern will be: [(number1, symbole, number2)]
    # or an empty list if no patterns was found in string
    if bool(pattern): # test if the list contain at least somthing with bool()
        nb1 = int(pattern[0][0])
        nb2 = int(pattern[0][2])
        sym = pattern[0][1]
        if sym in OPERATIONS:
            return OPERATIONS[sym](nb1,nb2)
        else:
            return "operation do not contain " + sym

print(calculate("8*-8"))
print(calculate("8/-8"))
print(calculate("8^-8"))
print(calculate("8--8"))
```

a not so easy, but extensible way to do it is with the regex (re) module

the `r"(-?\d)[ \t]*(.)[ \t]*(-?\d)"` can manage negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

You can first check which operator is used.

```
def calculate_from_string(value):
    # In case of the plus
    if "+" in value:
        # Split by this operator so u can get the numbers.
        numbers = value.split("+")
        # Do your logic
        return int(numbers[0]) + int(numbers[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

This code does `a+-*/b` but does not works for `a*-b`. That would require regular expressions.

```
def plus(a,b):
    return a+b

def minus(a,b):
    return a-b

def product(a,b):
    return a*b

def divide(a,b):
    return a/b

operate={'+':plus,'-':minus,'*':product,'/':divide}

def calculate_from_string(value):
    operators = ['+', '-', '*', '/']
    operator=[op for op in operators if op in value]
    nums=[float(n) for n in value.split(operator[0])]
    answer= operate[operator[0]](nums[0],nums[1])
    
    print(f"{nums[0]} {operator[0]} {nums[1]} = {answer}")
    return answer
    
calculate_from_string('2+3')
calculate_from_string('2-3')
calculate_from_string('2*3')
calculate_from_string('2/3')
>>> 2.0 + 3.0 = 5.0
>>> 2.0 - 3.0 = -1.0
>>> 2.0 * 3.0 = 6.0
>>> 2.0 / 3.0 = 0.6666666666666666
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a regular expression to match the arithmetic expression string,
e.g. the regex `(\-?[0-9]+)([\+\-\*/])(\-?[0-9]+)` matches two-operand operations with operands `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, also supporting negative numbers as operands, like

- `41+1`
- `43+-1`
- `-1+43`
- `84/2`
- ...

Consider the following (incomplete) example:

```
import re

def calc(expr: str) -> int:
    match = re.match('(\-?[0-9]+)([\+\-\*/])(\-?[0-9]+)', expr)
    operand1 = int(match.group(1))
    operator = match.group(2)
    operand2 = int(match.group(3))
    
    if (operator == '+'):
        return operand1 + operand2
    elif (operator == '-'):
        return operand1 - operand2
    elif (operator == '*'):
        return operand1 * operand2
    elif (operator == '/'):
        return operand1 / operand2
    else:
        raise 'Invalid operator: ' + operator


print(calc('41+1'))
print(calc('43+-1'))
```